# Airflow DAG failing - ERROR - HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm a noob on Apache Airflow. Literally just started and I'm running into an error. I wrote my first dag, and am calling a Python script. It successfully ran and worked initially when I set it up, and I scheduled it to run once a day. I came to check it today and the dag failed with the message  ERROR - HTTP Error 404: Not Found.

Everything is kinda new to me so apologies if this is an easy fix, but I don't understand why I'm getting a 404 Error. I've tried restarting docker to see if it was a webserver issue but no luck.

Thanks for the help

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmB2D.png)

#### DAG

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from covid_cases import covid_data


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 10, 4),
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20)}

dag =  DAG(dag_id = 'covid_updates',
           default_args = default_args,
           schedule_interval = "0 4 * * *")

t1 = PythonOperator(task_id = 'covid_update',
                    python_callable = covid_data,
                    dag = dag)

t1
```

#### PythonOperator - covid_cases.py

```
def covid_data():
    """

    Overview:
    ---------
    Downloads the USA COVID data directly from John Hopkins CSSEGISandData.
    This function merges all data from most current date to earliest date (2020-4-11).
    Using this function a user can conduct time series analysis in how COVID
    increases/decreases in various states.

    Output:
    -------
    One uncleaned .csv file called "usa_covid_cases.csv"


    """
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import pandas as pd
    from urllib.error import HTTPError

    # Set starting index
    i = 1

    # Earliest dataset available on GitHub
    start_date = datetime.strptime('2020-4-11', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

    # Pulling today's date minus 1 day due to delay posting on GitHub
    today = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=i)

    # Setting llist to store dataframe file names
    file_names = []

    # Looping until date is equal to earlist date = Start Date
    while not (start_date.day == today.day and start_date.month == today.month and start_date.year == today.year):

        # Extracting variables from current date
        day = today.day
        month = today.month
        year = today.year

        # Cleaning and converting values for formatting on GitHub URL link
        if day < 10:
            day = '0' + str(day)

        if month < 10:
            month = '0' + str(month)

        # Setting variable for each url
        url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/{}-{}-{}.csv'\
                    .format(month, day, str(year))

        try:
            # Reading each url as a datafra,
            df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)
        except HTTPError as e:
            # handle the error (print, log, etc)
            continue
        finally:
            # Code moved here to prevent an endless loop
            # Subtracting the new index to increase 1 less day from the current date
            today = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=i)

        # Saving each dataframe into the empty list
        file_names.append(df)

        # Increasing the index by 1
        i += 1

    # Once while loop ends - concat all the files into a single dataframe
    new_df = pd.concat(file_names)

    # Save output into new csv file
    new_df.to_csv('usa_covid_cases.csv')
```

Comment: Can you share your DAG code please?

Comment: @JordanM.added the code above.

Comment: Please add logs in text instead of pasting an image.

Comment: Also, if possible, show your covid_data function. What's evident from the logs at first glance is that you are trying to read in a dataframe from a URL like this : `pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)` and the URL no longer works, hence a 404.

Comment: @AmitSingh I added the covid_data function. The script works if I run it on command line or in jupyter, so I don't have issues with the URL there. Could it be that Airflow doesn't work with web links?

The DAG used to work so it strange that it runs into this error now

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, the error happens when you are trying to read data from a URL and that URL does not exists.

```py
pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False) #Line 50 of covid_data.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us) and the earliest dataset is from **04-12-2020**.

To prevent failing DAGs from possible deleted datasets you can wrap your `pd.read_csv()` in a `try except` block, like this:

```py
# Import the HTTPError (error from you screenshot)
from urllib.error import HTTPError
...

try:
    # Reading each url as a datafra,
    df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)
except HTTPError as e:
    # handle the error (print, log, etc)
    continue
finally:
    # Code moved here to prevent an endless loop
    # Subtracting the new index to increase 1 less day from the current date
    today = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=i)

 # Saving each dataframe into the empty list
 file_names.append(df)

 # Increasing the index by 1
 i += 1

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really appreciate the help. I made the changes to the file with your suggestions, the DAG ran really long and eventually failed with `ERROR - <urlopen error [Errno 0] Error>` I updated my post with the changes you suggested. Please take a look at the code, I believe I followed your try/except instructions.